# jQuery input value not changing immediately after html render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

As you can see here, this function is loading html onto the form class in my file. (quest[q) locates the proper html template to load from an array of templates not shown.

The html that is being loaded has a input with an id of p. As you can see I am trying to set the value of the input after loading.

I however can not get this to work.

The proper html gets loaded but the value does not get loaded. I would have to call the function twice (double click) to get the jquery to then change the value.

Any advice how to get this to work would be great. I have multiple templates with unique values that I would like to be reloaded dynamically. In the future, an id will be passed in the function to get the proper number that will be associated with the template that is being loaded. For now I'm just testing.

Thank you

This is the html that is getting loaded onto .form. See the ID #p.

```
<div class="question animated slideInUp">
    <h2>Enter Your Estimated Yearly Income</h2>
    <form onsubmit="Obj(this.income.name,this.income.value)">
        <input min=1 type="number" id="p" name="income" value="" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>
</div>


function redo(q) {

    q = Number(q);

    if (q + 1 != iterator) {
        iterator++;
        $('.form').load(quest[q])
        $('#p').val(data.income);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: It would be a lot easier to read this if the indentation were fixed. There are also missing closing brackets

Comment: I really didn't understand what you are trying to do and your code doesn't seem to include a lot of relevant info

Comment: There are no promises in the posted code, but `load` is async. You're not really telling us what the problem is here?

Comment: I edited the question to simply what I am trying to do, without promises.  The function redo gets called when the user wants to go back to the certain input to change the value. I would like the original value (data.income) to be loaded as that  input gets loaded.

Comment: Try something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/Lersos3k/

Comment: Just before you shared this I looked into the load doc and figured that out. Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

In .load you can use a callback function that is called after the html is rendered. This works to render the proper value into the input.

Unfortunately I had a brain fart but it works nice now!

```
function redo(q) {
console.log(data);
q = Number(q);
console.log(q);
if (q + 1 != iterator) {
    iterator++;
    return $('.form').load(quest[q],function(){
        $('#p').val(data.income);
    })


}
```

}